# Is there an adjective for intensity/force ending in "-al"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there an adjective of intensity (or similar term related to force) that ends in "-al"? like: space > spatial, time > temporal, etc.

Intensity is meant as the physical attribute/dimension of some physical phenomenon.

Sample sentence: "... the high (...adjetive of intensity needed here...), temporal [adjective of time], and spatial [adjective of space] resolving powers of macroscopic observations require that ... "

Comment: Can you give an example sentence? Why doesn't *intense* work?

Comment: for example, spatial-temporal refers to two dimensions easily.

Comment: @Oliver: Except it's usually [***spatio**-temporal*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spatio-temporal%2Cspatial-temporal&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: There's ***gravitational*** for the force of gravity, but the first other "fundamental force" that comes to mind is *electro-magnet**ic,*** which doesn't end in ***-al***. What exactly are we looking for here?

Comment: Agreed, just included the entry from the OED on spatial-temporal=spatiotemporal. Good point on the "magnetic" instance. I'm looking a way to refer to intensity as a "dimension" or "quality" ... as electric/electro, magnetic/magneto... etc.

Comment: I don't understand. Whether it's electrical, magnetic, or gravitational energy, all those things are "forces", for which any specific instantiation has "intensity". But I don't really see how "intensity" *itself* can be a meaningful "metric" with a measurable value unless context clearly establishes ***what "force" the intensity value applies to***.

Comment: for instance the intensity of an electric current is measured in Amperes

Comment: There's _intentional_, but it's a bit of a stretch to link it to _intensity_. The question is currently unclear regarding what context you have in mind. Try adding a sample sentence with a blank (___) in the spot the word should go.

Comment: ...and I suppose the intensity of gravitational force is measured in ***g***'s. But why do you say *the intensity of an electric current is measured in **Amperes***? Why not ***volts***? Anyway, those are both *specific* forces - there's no set of units for quantifying "force" in the abstract.

Comment: volts measure "voltage" = potential difference , not current :)

Comment: @Lawrence: e.g. the "... the high (____) temporal, and spatial resolving powers of macroscopic observations require that ... "

Comment: @OliverAmundsen What is that example sentence supposed to mean?

Comment: following Lawrence's request above

Comment: @OliverAmundsen Thanks. Note that on Stack Exchange, items in comments sections are considered to be ephemeral - moderators are free to delete them. Use the [edit] link below the post to make changes to the question. I've added your sample sentence for you, though I'd suggest editing the question or sample sentence so that it gives a sense of what you mean by "intensity". Are you talking about brightness of the observed phenomena, amplitude associated with the displayed image, how the observations are worded (very intense: "Wow, this is glorious!" vs not intense: "meh, it's alright."), etc?

Comment: Hi @Lawrence, thanks. Just edited the question. I mean intensity as a physical attribute/dimension of some physical phenomenon

Comment: Do you mean something like "because measurements of the particular quantity (intensity), the time, and the position are all very accurate, ... "?

Comment: Physicists would say the 'magnitude' of a force, not its intensity.

You could use 'magnitudinal' a word which seems to be in use while not appearing in any dictionaries.

Comment: Aren't you taking the advice "use parallelism in your sentences" a little too far here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **-al** ending means something like "pertaining or relating to the domain of"  (e.g. **gravitational**, pertaining to the domain of gravitation); but **intensity** itself is not a domain but a matter of *degree* and  it can apply to any domain with varying intensity; consider "intensity of color, intensity of pressure".  However, if the domain you have in mind is the *measurement* of intensity, then I'd concur with the suggestion made by tgdavies in the comments above: **magnitudinal**.

Answer (score 0):

- **Focal** maybe for focus
- **Impactful**
- **Existential** if you change the wording
- **Empirical** might be the most appropriate